Repeat master data in RTF Template
I'm trying to make a report in BI Publisher using Microsoft Word for creating the RTF template. The type of report I'm trying to create is a master - detail, composed by a region abobe with the master data and then all the detail data. Every master region with their details must abord a single page. The problem comes when the details exceed the page, in that case, I want to show the same master data whenever the details endure. Then when they finish, the report must do a page brake, and then start a new page with the following master data.
I'd like how to make this process in the RTF template.

What have you tried so far?
